# My menu is not dropping down, I can't access my inbox, and I can't even comment. What happened?

Tags: support

All the above is not working, and I can't even log off. Is this just my computer, or have I done something to my account?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try clearing your browser cache? Have you tried in a different web browser?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like JavaScript is disabled in your browser? Although if this is the case then you should get a warning displayed at the top of the page:

> English Language and Usage Meta -
>   Stack Exchange works best with
>   JavaScript enabled